# Wacom Bamboo CTH-300 issues

Tags: drivers, wacom, input-devices, input, bamboo

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 and am having issues with my Wacom Bamboo model CTH-300. The built in GUI to configure Wacom input devices doesn't recognize my Bamboo tablet at all.

When I issue - `dmesg | grep [Ww]acom` - my device is present however - `lsmod | grep [Ww]acom` - returns nothing. I know that the module exists and I issue - `sudo modprobe wacom` - and add the driver, yet nothing changes.

Here is the terminal output:

```
:~$ dmesg | grep [Ww]acom
[    3.222071] usb 6-1: Manufacturer: Wacom Co.,Ltd.


:~$ lsmod | grep [Ww]acom
wacom                  62341  0
```

And the full `dmesg` output:

```
[ 1131.802099] usbcore: registered new interface driver wacom
[ 1191.268404] usb 6-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 1193.073724] usb 6-1: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ohci-pci
[ 1193.247785] usb 6-1: New USB device found, idVendor=056a, idProduct=0319
[ 1193.247804] usb 6-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1193.247813] usb 6-1: Product: Bamboo Pad, wireless
[ 1193.247821] usb 6-1: Manufacturer: Wacom Co.,Ltd.
```

Any input would be very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The driver is not in the linux kernel for that device id.  See Launchpad bug 1265714:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/xf86-input-wacom/+bug/1265714